# Use Rails Foundation for one module within an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, zurb-foundation, asset-pipeline

I'm working on application 'A' that's already built but foundation is not used. Now I need to work on another module 'B' that's within the same application 'A' but with foundation.

I have added gems 'compass-rails' & 'foundation-rails' in Gemfile and then run 'bundle install' & 'rails g foundation:install'.

**Problem:**

- When I include "*= require foundation_and_overrides" in *application.scss* then it affects the entire application 'A'.

**What is required:**

- I need to add "*= require foundation_and_overrides" only for module 'B' views so that the entire application won't get affected.

**Queries:**

- Is there any possibility that we can use two different *application.scss* for rails application? Like I want to use *A.scss* (for application wide doesn't include foundation) and *B.scss* (only for module B with foundation).

Please help me out how I should cater this particular scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The application.css is included by the layout (usually `/views/layout/application.html.erb`) with the instruction

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

You should create a new application.scss with the fundation CSSs, and either:

- create new layout which calls the new application.scss, et choose per controller which layout to use (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302954/rails-layout-per-controller))
- using the same layout, add instructions to choose which application.css to include (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602147/javascript-file-per-view-in-rails))

Comment: Thanks for your response. That helped me.